# Conditions for the programmatically created Dropdown list do not work

Tags: development, asp.net

The conditions for the programmatically created *DropdownList* do not work. When I click on **CopyData**, condition does not work and the *DropdownList* is reset to the beginning.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="monthdrop" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["NetworkNodes"];
                    monthdrop.DataTextField = "Title";
                    monthdrop.DataValueField = "Title";
                    monthdrop.DataBind();            
                }
            }



protected void CopyData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string selectedText = monthdrop.SelectedValue;

            if (selectedText == "Test1") {
                EmptySearch.Visible = true;
                EmptySearch.InnerHtml = "Test1";

            } else if (selectedText == "Test2")
            {
               EmptySearch.Visible = true;
               EmptySearch.InnerHtml = "Test2";
            } 
        }
```

If I apply the conditions to the simple *DropdownList*, then everything works:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="monthdrop" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem Value="Test1">Test1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="Test3">Test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

 protected void CopyData(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string selectedText = monthdrop.SelectedValue;

                if (selectedText == "Test1") {
                    EmptySearch.Visible = true;
                    EmptySearch.InnerHtml = "Test1";

                } else if (selectedText == "Test2")
                {
                   EmptySearch.Visible = true;
                   EmptySearch.InnerHtml = "Test2";
                } 
            }
```

Comment: where is dropdown bind function? is it on page load?

Comment: Yes, Page Load ))

Comment: do you have this code surrounding if(!page.postback) ?

Comment: Wow, thanks, it;s working )))

Comment: Welcome, added solution as answer, please upvote and mark as answer for other's reference....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you code in !Page.IsPostBack() so that dropdown does not get render again post back.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["NetworkNodes"];
                    monthdrop.DataTextField = "Title";
                    monthdrop.DataValueField = "Title";
                    monthdrop.DataBind();            
                }
            }
    }
}
```